# The 'patch' method generating a 500 error when recieving a pk in the URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I'm sending a PATCH request (naturally) passing a pk and I'm getting a `TypeError: patch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'`

These are the request parameters I'm sending:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/task/toggle-done/1/
Request headers: {'Authorization': 'Token 13f2f18ea582e9c585c817ba52358b5b19e696a8', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '0'}
Request method: PATCH
Request body: None
```

This is the URL Patterns:

`path('task/toggle-done/<int:pk>/', TaskToggleDoneAPIView.as_view(), name='task_toggle_done'),`

This is the `TaskToggleDoneAPIView` implementation

```
class TaskToggleDoneAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['patch']
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsObjectOwner]
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def patch(self, request,):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.done = not instance.done
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
gtd-api-1    | Internal Server Error: /api/task/toggle-done/1/
gtd-api-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
gtd-api-1    |     response = get_response(request)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
gtd-api-1    |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
gtd-api-1    |     return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
gtd-api-1    |     return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
gtd-api-1    |     response = self.handle_exception(exc)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
gtd-api-1    |     self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
gtd-api-1    |     raise exc
gtd-api-1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
gtd-api-1    |     response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
gtd-api-1    | TypeError: patch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'
gtd-api-1    | "PATCH /api/task/toggle-done/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 78560
gtd-api-1    | Internal Server Error: /api/task/toggle-done/1/
gtd-api-1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
```

If I'm getting everything right, the `lookup_field = 'pk'` should be handling it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `patch()` method must receive `pk` as an argument so:

```py
class TaskToggleDoneAPIView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    http_method_names = ['patch']
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,IsObjectOwner]
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer

    def patch(self, request, pk):
        instance = self.get_object()
        instance.done = not instance.done
        instance.save()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
  def patch(self, request,):
```

To:

```
  def patch(self, request, pk):
```